# Commands or tools to send messages from Ubuntu to Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, lan

Are there any commands or tools for sending messages from Ubuntu to Windows XP that *don't* require me to install any client software on the Windows PC?

I'm looking for something like `net send` in Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Samba in Ubuntu to accomplish this. Simply type:

```
smbclient -M computername
```

where computername is the netbios name of the pc you're sending the message to. You can then type your message and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>D</kbd> to send.

Comment: Does this use the messenger service in xp?

Comment: @JNK yes, it does.